# Additional html.erb file in View not Working in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, view

I have a database I created in ruby on rails which automatically created some of the needed files but when I manually added an additional file in the views folder and try to access it in my browser .
This error appears

```html
Routing Error

No route matches [GET] "/second/count"
Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.
```

I tried to correct this by putting a number sign in the routes.rb

```html
Community::Application.routes.draw do
  #resources :seconds


match ':controller(/:action(/:id))', :via => :get
```

The file I just created worked but then the files automatically created won't.
This error appears

```html
NameError in Seconds#index

Showing c:/Sites/Community/app/views/seconds/index.html.erb where line #25 raised:

undefined local variable or method `new_second_path' for #<#<Class:0x456ee80>:0x37b9a98>
Extracted source (around line #25):

22: 
23: <br />
24: 
25: <%= link_to 'New Second', new_second_path %>
Rails.root: c:/Sites/Community

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/views/seconds/index.html.erb:25:in `_app_views_seconds_index_html_erb__742794588_29296056'
app/controllers/seconds_controller.rb:7:in `index'
Request

Parameters:

None
Show session dump

Show env dump

Response

Headers:

None
```

Comment: Is `#resources :seconds` supposed to be commented out in the routes?

Comment: I don't really know :D I'm quite new to this so I just experiment on some parts.

Comment: Then reading some basic tutorial will help you to understand things better https://www.railstutorial.org/book.

Comment: Ok, then i'll answer my own question - no, it shouldn't be commented out.  Like @maximus says read some tutorials.  Uncomment `resources :seconds` and type `rake routes` in your console - this will show you all the routes available to you, which you can add `_path` to the end.

Comment: Thanks for the advice and the resource :), I'll make sure to do more research next time I ask another question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the helper `new_second_path` to work, you have to uncomment the line `resources :seconds` in the routes.

Unless you know what you are doing, I would comment the line `match ...` which is a catch-all.

Also: a path `/second/count` will not work, it should be `/seconds/count`. To explain this:

- `/second/count`: with your `match` it will look for `SecondController` (singular!!) and action `count`

But the clean way to handle is to write:

```
resources :seconds do 
  collection do 
    get :count
  end
end
```

This will allow you to write `count_seconds_path` in your view, which will render the correct link (`/seconds/count`).